# Image max height 100% inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am getting a glitch when setting max-height and max-width of an image inside a flex container.

Following is the css for flex container

```
.galleria-images{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  flex : 1; /* It's also a flex item hence take default height available in viewport */
}
```

Now my application is to have a child image to flex container which is centred on both axis. But it should not exceed height or width of a parent container (flex container). I also don't want image to shrink or grow to maintain aspect ratio. Hence I wrote following css.

```
img{
    flex:0 0 auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

But this is now working out for me. Even though flex container has flexible height, image inside it is overflowing.

[image]

This works when the viewport orientation is changed. As shown below.

[image]

**Anything else that can be done???**

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdqvcb1k/)

```css
.galleria {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  right: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.galleria .galleria-images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
.galleria .galleria-images img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.galleria .galleria-thumbs {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="galleria">
  <div class="galleria-images">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/06/13/07/32/cactus-1453793_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="galleria-thumbs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The image element is ignoring its direct parent because it has a static position. Try making the parent element relatively positioned and make the image absolutely positioned:

```
.galleria-images {
    position: relative;
}

.galleria-images img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4w7t61u/

Answer (score 7):

You can try using **[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)**, and make sure to check out the browser support [tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

> The `object-fit` CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

```
.galleria .galleria-images img {
  ...
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain; /*or "cover" depends on what you need*/
}
```

And try adjusting `justify-content` value as needed.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77ajcusL/)**

```css
.galleria {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  right: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.galleria .galleria-images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
  overflow: auto;
}
.galleria .galleria-images img {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
.galleria .galleria-thumbs {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="galleria">
  <div class="galleria-images">
    <img src="//unsplash.it/800/600?image=0">
    <img src="//unsplash.it/800/600?image=1">
    <img src="//unsplash.it/800/600?image=2">
  </div>
  <div class="galleria-thumbs">
    thumbnails
  </div>
</div>
```

Both IE 11 and Edge don't support `object-fit` currently, I would also suggest to use background image instead of inline images, e.g.

```
<div style="background:url("path/to/image.jpg") center / contain;">
```