# DIsplay: flex takes image height but overflows when text is added

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

My `display: flex` container takes my images height but when I add text it overflows the image. Basically the inspector takes the images height but forgets about the added text.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.book-right-side {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.attraction-card {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.book-right-side img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-right-side">

  <div class="attraction-card">
    <h4>Beijing City</h4>
    <p>Teeest</p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Beijing_montage.png" alt="Beijing City" />
  </div>


  <div class="attraction-card">
    <h4>Zhangjiajie Forest</h4>
    <p>Teeest</p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Badaling_China_Great-Wall-of-China-04.jpg" alt="Zhangjiajie Forest" />
  </div>


  <div class="attraction-card">
    <h4>Great Wall of China</h4>
    <p>Teeest</p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Badaling_China_Great-Wall-of-China-04.jpg" alt="Great Wall of China" />
  </div>


</div>
```

Error:

[image]

and the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqbcmvox/3/

Comment: Check if this is a duplicate of this Question - [image-max-height-100-inside-flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251537/image-max-height-100-inside-flexbox). If so, maybe checkout those answers.

Comment: Yes, it's a similar question but the answers don't help, still thanks for trying. I think I solved my problem but I'll leave the question open in case someone will have a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `div` tag to wrap the image and set the height to 100% `{height: 100%}`.

I've tested it and it works. I resized the images of the same height, and width and hosted them on a free hosting image online.

```
<div> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/F4qbx7V/great-wall-21.jpg"> </div>
<div> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vZTJ9WN/Beijing-montage1.jpg"> </div>
```

Also, add a `height: 100%` on your `.attraction-card`. Without adding the height the image looks stretched (if you notice).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/reagandev/pen/yLoVdaq?editors=1100)

Comment: I only used height on `.attraction-card` and it 'solved' the problem, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the h4 and p tag in a div, then give that div a class, and make it an absolute, and make the attraction card relative to that absolute, for example:

```
.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.attraction-card{
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I wanted them to look just like in my photo, i don't want the text to be placed on the photo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your problem

```
.book-right-side {
      display: flex;
      gap: 1rem;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it cuts the images, the thing is that I want everything to look just like my picture but I don't understand why the inspector doesn't get the correct height

Comment: I believe, this will hide part of the image (at the bottom), and entire image might not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `<img>` tag with a `<div>` tag.

This will make sure that the image doesn't overload the size of the parent flex div.

Example:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Badaling_China_Great-Wall-of-China-04.jpg" alt="Beijing City" />
</div>
```

Do this for all 3 instances of the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I found this solution, and the other one is giving the .attraction-card a `height: 100%` but I thought there could be a better solution because it shortens the images on display, and all images need to have same dimensions to be displayed nicely